# Importing Excel workbooks into Mathematica to export them as worksheets, within a single Excel workbook

Tags: export, import, list-manipulation

I have 70 Excel workbooks (in .xlsx format)
that I need to import into Mathematica.

The first workbook contains the following table:
[image: Excel Workbook 1]

The second workbook contains the following table:
[image: Excel Workbook]

and I have 68 more workbooks that obey the exact same format.

How can I import those 70 Excel workbooks into Mathematica;
so that I can in turn export them into a single Excel workbook that
contains 70 worksheets?  The first worksheet could be called
"221100"; the second could be called "221200"; etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a [`"Directory"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Directory.html) [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) and then [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) [`"XLSX"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/XLSX.html) with the `"Sheets"` syntax and `"Rules"` parameter.

First copy the 70 files to a their own directory without any other .xlsx files. You do not need to rename the files but all the .xlsx files in the directory will be imported.

Then import all `"XLSX"` files in the directory.

```
xlsxData = Import["<directory path>", {"Directory", "*.xlsx"}];
```

Next construct the `"Sheets"` `Export` syntax with the first sheet of each workbook and take the sheet name from the first cell of the first sheet.

```
sheets = StringTrim@*First@StringSplit[#[[1, 1, 1]], "-"] -> #[[1, 2 ;;]] & /@ xlsxData;
```

Finally `Export` to one workbook.

```
Export["<path>"<>"stuff.xlsx", "Sheets" -> sheets, "Rules"]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

One way may be the following:

- create a folder on the desktop and name *workbooks*;
- enter the folder 70 file.xlsx;
- numbers such files from 1 to 70;
- in MMA do work the following code:

---

```
datasheets = Table[0, 70];

namesheets = Table[0, 70];

For[i = 1, i <= 70, i++,

datasheets = ReplacePart[datasheets, 
i -> Import["C:\\Users\\TeM\\Desktop\\workbooks\\" <> ToString[i] <> ".xlsx"]];

namesheets = ReplacePart[namesheets, 
i -> "\"MySheet" <> ToString[i] <> "\"\[Rule]datasheets[[" <> ToString[i] <> "," <> "1]]"]];

Export["C:\\Users\\Manu\\Desktop\\workbooks\\merge.xlsx", 
                  {ToExpression[namesheets]}, {{"Sheets"}}];
```

---

where, of course, you will have to fix the address of the folder and wanting well as the names of the excel sheets. In that folder you will find the desired "merge.xlsx".

Comment: I'm having trouble importing the files using the For[i=1, i<=70, i++...

Comment: I use:  setDir := 
 Quiet@Check[SetDirectory@DirectoryName@$InputFileName, 
   SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]]  I can then import the workbooks into Mathematica using:                                                               workbook1 = 
  Import["1-221100.xlsx", {"Sheets", "Projection Results", All}]; workbook2 = 
  Import["2-221200.xlsx", {"Sheets", "Projection Results", All}]; etc. because the worksheet containing the data in each of the 70 input workbooks is called "Projection Results".  How can I modify the above For[i=1, i<70, i++ ... program to import the workbooks?  Thanks!